# Maximize a bivariate function in Maple

Tags: optimization, maple

I have the following function ($\theta$ is a parameter with known value, e.g. $\theta=1$): 
$$
f:=\frac{xy}{1+\theta (1-x)(1-y)}
$$
and I want to maximize its second-order partial derivative in Maple for  $x,y\in [0,1]$. My code was as follows:

$$
fxy:=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}f
$$

I use "maximize()" as follows, but it gives me the wrong answer:

```
Optimization:-Maximize(fxy, x = 0 .. 1, y = 0 .. 1)
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: What is $\theta$?  Another variable to be optimized?  A parameter with a known value?  Could it be negative?

Comment: $\theta$ is a parameter with a known value. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Maple's `Optimization` package offers only local solvers for nonconvex multivariate problems. So the initial point can matter.

Forcing a more fortuitous initial point, or another method, can help. Eg,

```
restart;
f := x*y/(1+theta*(1-x)*(1-y)):
fxy := diff(eval(f,theta=1),x,y):

Optimization:-Maximize(fxy, x = 0 .. 1, y = 0 .. 1,
                       method=modifiednewton);

                 [2., [x = 0., y = 1.]]

Optimization:-Maximize(fxy, x = 0 .. 1, y = 0 .. 1,
                       method=sqp, initialpoint=[x=0.51,y=0.49]);

                 [2., [x = 1., y = 0.]]
```

Unfortunately, with this particular choice of range the default method appears to be returning a saddle point (likely using an initial point of `[0.5,0.5]`).

```
# uses method=sqp here
sad := Optimization:-Maximize(fxy, x = 0 .. 1, y = 0 .. 1);

      sad := [1.03521665624990256,
             [x = 0.552786404455194, y = 0.552786404455196]]

eval(diff(fxy,x),sad[2]), eval(diff(fxy,y),sad[2]);

                            -10                     -10
         1.93439708695564 10   , 1.93446592078317 10   

plots:-display(
  plots:-pointplot3d([[eval([x,y],sad[2])[],sad[1]]],
                     color=red,symbolsize=30,symbol=solidsphere),
  plot3d(fxy, x=0..1, y=0..1)
);
```

[image]

Using a global solver can make this easier. Below I'll use the 3rd party add-on `DirectSearch` package.

```
DirectSearch:-GlobalSearch(fxy, [x=0..1, y=0..1], maximize);

 [[1.99999999774906, [x = 0.999999999969016, y = 0.1063501190*10^(-8)], 68],
  [1.99999999741613, [x = 0.7116227275*10^(-9), y = 0.999999999709843], 65]])
```

In recent Maple versions (eg, Maple 2017 and newer) you can install that add-on package directly from Maple itself, via the MapleCloud sign-in (top right of the main menu icon bar). Or by downloading from its [site](https://maple.cloud/app/5728547235692544/DirectSearch) on the MapleCloud.

In version Maple 2016, etc, the `DirectSearch ver.2` package can still be downloaded for installation from the [Application Center](https://de.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=101333).